# How can I restrict clients to login?

Tags: magento-1.9, login

I wan't to make sure that only an "authorized"/certified customer can login in my Magento Store.

I need to certify a specific customer. It's something like a 'check email for login' but for me (not for the customer). So then I can say that I wan't to sell to this customer or not.

Is there any default options or extensions to do something like this?

Thanks,
Rafael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this module from the excellent Vinai:

https://github.com/Vinai/customer-activation

It's open source and very light. Easy for you to adjust the logic if you want it to behave slightly differently.

Comment: Hi, Thanks, but I need to certify a specific customer. It's something like a 'check email for login' but for me (not for the customer). So then I can say that I wan't to sell to this customer or not.

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood your original question, I have edited my answer :)